# combine two URLs REGEX

Tags: regex

I have data from two URLS that I need to combine using REGEX

```
/online-teaching
/online-teaching?fbclid
```

I have `/(online-teaching)|(online teaching)`

I can't figure out how to include the url with the ? and the one without.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `\/online[- ]teaching(?:\?\w+)?`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/AyAZFU/1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to an answer) if it answers your question. In this way your question stops from show up as _unanswered_. Also up-vote good answers. – As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

How about something as simple as:

```
online-teaching(?:.+)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LycDNI/1)

Match `online-teaching` and anything that follows, if it exists (might need to constraint for specific characters instead of matching all with `.` to have a valid URL, but I'll leave that up to you).

Comment: If you're going to allow _anything_ after "teaching", not just a question mark, then you don't need the non-capturing group, you can just use `.*`. However, I don't think that's what the OP wants.